The derivative of semigroup in the weak sense imply strong sense
Suppose $X$ is a Banach space, and $T(t)$ $t\ge0$ is a strongly continuous semigroup with generator $A$. Assume $\frac{T(t)-I}{t}x$ weakly converges to $y\in X$ when $t\to 0$, then I need to prove $x\in D(A)$ and $y=Ax$. Could you provide some help?
It's asked in MSE but no responses received.

This is proved for example in Pazy's "Semigroups of Linear Operators and Applications to Partial Differential Equations", section 2.1 "Weak Equals Strong".

@unwissen Thanks!
